# Synchronization time with database

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, jdbc

I have auction system application and in thread I connect with database to check that if auction is over. If I don't have any Thread.sleep() then it shows this error: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found.
How Can I check if auction is finished without using of Thread.sleep();

```
private class AuctionRunnable implements Runnable {
        private int[] items;
        private String baseUser;
        public AuctionRunnable(int[] items,String baseUser)
        {
            this.items=items;
            this.baseUser = baseUser;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
            {
                while (checkTime(baseUser)) // sprawdza czy aukcja zakonczona
                    {
                        available = true;
                        //Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                available = false;
                // Found winner
            }
        }
    }

public boolean checkTime(String user) {
        String lsql = "SELECT END_DATE FROM AUCTIONS WHERE SYSDATE<END_DATE";
        DBWork db = new DBWork(user);
        ResultSet lres;
        try {
            lres = db.RunQuery(lsql);

            while (lres.next()) {

                try {
                    db.terminate();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TwoServers2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you remove the sleep, you would be querying the DB way too fast.

Comment: Can you show the code for checkTime method? Maybe you can use a connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you do in `DBWork db = new DBWork(user);`, but I assume you are opening a connection to the database. The database will only allow a certain number of connections at a particular time. Every time you make a query, you make a new connection to the DB. Your termination of the connection to the database is dependent on `while (lres.next())` so if the result set doesn't return anything, then you never terminate the connection to the database for the previous query. After enough calls to `checkTime(String user)` the total amount of connections available get used up. So having the sleep slows the rate at which you open connections to the DB.

Rather then making a new connection for every time you query the DB, can you move the Connection object outside of the while loop , initialize a connection to the db first , then do your queries on that connection object. Something like this

```
    import java.sql.* ;

public class SqlSpeed{

    private String threadName;
    private Thread t;
    private static Connection connection;



    public SqlSpeed( String name){
        this.threadName = name;
        this.connection = null;
        }

    /*******************************************************************
    /--Looks for the mariaDB driver
    /*******************************************************************/
    private void findDBdriver(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

/*******************************************************************
/--Initilizes the connection Object 
/*******************************************************************/

public Connection initDB(){
    findDBdriver();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";  
        String USER = "----";
        String PASS = "-----";
        connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: No Connection to DB can be made  !");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    this.connection = connection;
    return connection;
}

public void run(){

 //use the connection object for your SQL quierres  

}




public static void main(String[] args){

    SqlSpeed test = new SqlSpeed("test");
    test.initDB();
    }
}
```

**your only gonna want the Connection static if your all threads are gonna use the same sql account.